# How to speed up deletion of all RDF subjects of a determined type?

Tags: rdf, sparql, jena

I'm executing the following piece of code with Jena to delete all statements involving a subject with type `ItemDespesa`:

```
    StmtIterator it = m.listStatements(null, ResourceFactory.createProperty(RDF("type")), ResourceFactory.createResource(LOA("ItemDespesa")));
    ArrayList l = new ArrayList<Statement>();
    while (it.hasNext()) {
        Statement n = it.nextStatement();
        StmtIterator it2 = m.listStatements(n.getSubject(), null, (RDFNode)null);
        while (it2.hasNext()) l.add(it2.nextStatement());
    }
    m.remove(l);
```

...which I guess would be equivalent to the following SPARQL:

```
DELETE WHERE {
     ?x rdf:type loa:ItemDespesa
     ?x ?y ?z
}
```

However, this takes about 15 minutes to execute in a database with 5.342.213 tuples. How to go about this more efficiently?

Comment: Have you tried the SPARQL version?

Comment: What storage are you using?  In-memory? Putting things into an ArrayList can be surprisingly expensive as it internally grows slowly (*1.5).  This also interacts with the garbage collector. Pre-allocating a large array can be noticeably faster.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As described in @AndyS' comment, changing the container from `ArrayList` to `LinkedList` made it execute in seconds. However, it required the Java heap space to be turned bigger.